# copying data from textfile to windows form in c#

Tags: c#

i have a text file in which i have stored employee id,name and his phone no seperated by ":"
i want to load these details in windows form such that all employee ids should come in one listbox so that user can select one out of them .how to do it using c#. please help me

Comment: Which bit are you having difficulties with? Can you post your current code and point out the problems?

Answer (score 3):

Open a text file stream to that file, read and parse each line creating an Employee class instance for each of them, add each Employee to a `List<Employee>`, bind the list to the listbox using the name as display member

```
class Employee
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public string PhoneNumber {get; set;}
}
```